# Приложение ломающее систему

Tags: c++

Программа должна угадать число пользователя с 7 попыток

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    cout << "Задумайте целое число от 1 до 100" << endl;
    int middle;
    int lower = 1;
    int upper = 100;

    char answer;
    while (lower < upper) {
        middle = (lower + upper) / 2;
        if (answer == 'y') {

        }
        else if (answer == 'n') {
            upper -= middle;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Введите корректное значение (y/n)";
        }
        cout << "Ваше число " << middle;
    }
}
```

При компиляции экран выводит много текста зависает потом белеет ,а система летит к чертям.

Comment: Много текста и зависание при компиляции или при запуске? Что конкретно значит "система летит к чертям"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты не просишь ввести в цикле букву. Думаю предполагалось что-то такое:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    cout << "Задумайте целое число от 1 до 100" << endl;
    int middle;
    int lower = 1;
    int upper = 100;

    char answer;
    while (lower < upper) {
        middle = (lower + upper) / 2;
        cin >> answer; // Просишь ввести букву
        if (answer == 'y') {
            break; // если да то выходишь из цикла
        }
        else if (answer == 'n') {
            upper -= middle;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Введите корректное значение (y/n)";
        }
        cout << "Ваше число " << middle;
    }
}
```

Невозможно было нарушить цикл, так как не просил ввод, и в итоге получился бесконечный цикл.